# How to reference without copying a library project on Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Yes, everywhere I can learn how to make a module from a project that will copy the library project. But that's no good, since a change in the library project would have to be replicated on every project that uses it. So, how can I reference it from a folder that's outside the project in a dynamic way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Got it:
In your project, go in settings.gradle and declare something like this:

`include ':LibReferenceName'
project(':LibReferenceName').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../relativePath/toThe/libraryModule/fromTheProject')`

And at the modules that requires the library, include something like this in the build.gradle of it:

`compile project(path: ':LibReferenceName')`

You can also not use settingsDir and just put the absolute path of the project.

Comment: With AndroidX it's "implemention" instead of "compile", right?

Comment: Good thing this is about android studio then.