# Android Studio - Creating Modules without copying files?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm creating projects with dependencies in Android Studio. I know how to link projects by adding modules.

But I realized that 'importing modules' create a copy of the libProject inside the project.

Is there a way to prevent that ? Like an 'external module' ?

Since i'm in charge of both project, I want to be able to push changes to the libProject Repo, without having to copy paste files between folders.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reference without copying a library project on Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24494105/how-to-reference-without-copying-a-library-project-on-android-studio)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. The module needs to have a Gradle build file set up for it. If it's got that, then in the project you're linking to it, add this to the **settings.gradle** file at the project root:

```
include ':libraryName'
project(':libraryName').projectDir=new File('/path/to/library')
```

where the path you specify in the second line is the path to the directory containing the library's **build.gradle** file. The path can be relative or absolute.

Comment: Thanks works perfectly! Is there a reason the settings.gradle is read-only ? I used Sublime to edit the file .

Comment: I don't know why it would be read-only. Must be something specific about your project or source control.

Comment: I am having a problem with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898060/gradle-dependencies-in-folder-above-project

Comment: @ScottBarta this works like a charm, thanks for saving me hours of digging around!

Comment: I have added the lines, but the main app does not compile because it does not find the package defined in the library. What should I look for?

Comment: Add the new project as a module dependency now

Comment: This does not work any more as of Android studio 1.2.1. Does any one have workaround for this new version?

Comment: @peceps still working in android studio 1.4, don't forget to add the library to build.gradle dependencies as `compile project(path: ':libraryName')`.

Comment: I created a project "ScreenSaver" and a module inside it named "screensaver" 
Path for the project is "C:\Users\sadip_000\StudioProjects\mp\"
and module is "C:\Users\sadip_000\StudioProjects\mp\ScreenSaver\"
But the gradle says project with path not found
what might be the issue?

Comment: Why do they have to make it so hard?

Comment: I was wrong because didn't attention to second part of accepted answer where it says **where the path you specify in the second line is the path to the directory containing the library's build.gradle file. The path can be relative or absolute.**

Comment: I thought this might not work anymore (v4.1.2) - I discovered I had to **Sync Project With Gradle Files** after starting up AS to get it to reload properly.

Answer (score 20):

The solution:

```
include ':libraryName'
project(':libraryName').projectDir=new File('/path/to/library')
```

was not working for me. After couple of wasted hours I figured out the issue. There are two `build.gradle` files, one for project and one for library name. If the library is in the folder **'\MyLib'** then there will be a `build.gradle` in **'\MyLib'** and another at **'\MyLib\app'**. You have to point to the **'\MyLib\app'** and not **'\Mylib'**.

Hopefully this saves some time for others.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this!  I wasted hours on this.

Answer (score 2):

If you have, like myself, have multiple modules (*I only realised today that copies were included, I thought that the project included links to the source.*)

You can have multiple modules/projects along the lines of :-

```
include ':app', ':sqlwords', ':dbindex', ':dbcolumn', ':dbtable', ':dbdatabase', ':displayhelp', ':pickdate'
project(':sqlwords').projectDir= new File('d:/Android_Applications/Modules/sqlwords')
project(':dbcolumn').projectDir= new File('d:/Android_Applications/Modules/dbcolumn')
project(':dbtable').projectDir= new File('d:/Android_Applications/Modules/dbtable')
project(':dbindex').projectDir= new File('d:/Android_Applications/Modules/dbindex')
project(':dbdatabase').projectDir= new File('d:/Android_Applications/Modules/dbdatabase')
project(':displayhelp').projectDir= new File('d:/Android_Applications/Modules/displayhelp')
project(':pickdate').projectDir= new File('d:/Android_Applications/PickDateShowCase/pickdate')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **android { sourceSets{ main.java.srcDirs += '../../../library/src' }}** in your app **build.gradle** . Not sure about supporting all android resources, for pure java library works well.