# Android Studio transition and using sub libraries / sharing libraries

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, dependencies

I am trying to transition all our projects from Eclipse to Android Studio (Finally decided i had to do it..!) but i am fighting seriously with the way how Android Studio / gradle works - in regard to using external library projects.

Until now in Eclipse - we used to have all the dependent projects in the same workspace and they where 'shared' amongst all projects which were under development.

That made it extremely nice to do changes on the external changes and commit them separately to their own SVN repos - while the projects using them - to take advantage of the changes without thinking.

That goes specifically to one library - our own framework which we use for all android projects and it is constantly being developed, altered, partially reworked and used by several people.

But then came Android Studio... the problem is that say if i have an example project with 10 sublibrary dependencies, including our framework - Android Studio with physically COPY all files into a subfolder of the main root project - loosing all the capabilities to 'commit' changes later being done to the sub libraries - to their own SVN repos.

I've tried pretty much everything, i think i've read everything :) but crap - nothing seems to 'fix' my work case..

I tried to checkout one sublibrary in the already checked out root folder of the root project and tried to import it into it - but ofcourse Android Studio says 'library already exists' - so that doesn't work. Even if it did... the library itself has its own deps and what i saw is that Android Studio will decouple them upon import and put them at the same level in the root project.. which completely messes everything up.

So my question is - even if i understand this is no longer possible - is there any EASY way i can at least COMMIT BACK to the SVN repo of the sublibrary from within the root owning project - using Android Studio (by easy i mean from the UI directly without needing to mess with manual console merge hazzle...)

I can't understand how anyone has not solved this yet - i am sure everyone is doing this one way or another?

Could someone share a good practice way of 'doing' it? :)

THANK YOU!

Comment: good practice - use Git :-) also use proper versioning of your libraries release them and rely on this separate repo and release builds.

Comment: Does this help you? You can use modules in-place instead of having it import a copy of them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658422/android-studio-0-8-1-creating-modules-without-copying-files/24659324#24659324

Comment: What i did was use Blundell's advice - although i really... really ... REALLY didn't want to go switching completely to git... We have over 300 repos here in SVN and it's really not the time to start the git hazzle... But this was the only workable solution so far as git externals make it really really easy to work in such way. The f**** up thing about this is that half work has to go to console again... Externals and adding git remotes can't be managed from Android Studio... Life, i guess :) Thank you both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did:

- Switched to: git
- Converted our subprojects to git from svn
- Made all subprojects externals of the primary project
- Included the subprojects in gradle with the help of this post: [Android Studio 0.8.1 Creating Modules without copying files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658422/android-studio-0-8-1-creating-modules-without-copying-files/24659324#24659324)

Cons:

- Not fully manageable from Android Studio - have to do half commits in Studio, the other half + pushes in console - so i ditched Studio completely and moved all to console once again. May be this ain't so bad after all :)

What i did was use Blundell's advice - although i really... really ... REALLY didn't want to go switching completely to git...

We have over 300 repos here in SVN and it's really not the time to start the git hazzle...

But this was the only workable solution so far as git externals make it really really easy to work in such way.

The f**** up thing about this is that half work has to go to console again... Externals and adding git remotes can't be managed from Android Studio... Life, i guess :)