# Link module from external project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm migrating all my project from Eclipse to Android Studio (1.0.2, just download it yesterday) but having issue with external module.

In Eclipse, I have workspace like this

[image]

All the activities, fragments, models and classes are in 'Core' project. The Core project required some libraries to work (Such as Google Play Service, Facebook or Twitter) While App 1, App 2, App 3 and so on are just while label apps. Those app doesn't contain anything except icons, configuration files, loading images etc.

I manage to import "Core" app and all it dependencies to Android Studio as a new project. When I build the core, **I got 0 errors and 0 warnings**

[image]

Then, I create new project call "Test" and link "Core" project to it by following selected answer from this question

[How to share a single library source across multiple projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243269/how-to-share-a-single-library-source-across-multiple-projects)

**setting.gradle of Test Project**

```
include ':Test'
include '..:..:AppyCore:Core'
```

**build.gradle of Test Project**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile project('..:..:AppyCore:Core')
}
```

But, when I rebuild project, I got this error

```
Error:(41, 0) Project with path ':SlidingMenu' could not be found in project '..:..:AppyCore:Core'
```

When I double click the error message, IDE show me build.gradle of the Core project and highlight the dependency part of the file as following

[image]

Seems like when I try to build the "Test" project, it can't locate all the dependencies of "Core" project. Do you know how to fix this?

**Note**

- I believe that the "Core" project setup is already correct because I did create "Test 2" app and import "Core" project into the same root directory, same project. It was working without any issue. But this is not an option because I actually have about 20+ white label app. It will be super difficult to update one by one if each of those app has it own "Core".
- I think the directory that I include is correct, otherwise, I'll instead get this error

  "Error: Configuration with name 'default' not found."

(I tried by intentionally put wrong directory and got this same error)

Comment: Wow...I liked your question. This must be referenced as an example question. Great job!

Comment: I would recommend using `projectDir` in your **settings.gradle** file instead of `..:..` syntax. That might help untangle the dependencies. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658422/android-studio-0-8-1-creating-modules-without-copying-files/24659324#24659324

Comment: I know this question is a bit old, but if you still haven't figured it out, it would be good if you could post your different build.gradle files and the settings.gradle file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to make a new project for each app version, and link them to a common codebase. In this scenario, it's much better to use the "variant" feature of Gradle. With it, each app is a "variant" of the core app, with has its own package name, its own resource files, and even its own src files.

To do so you need to:

1. modify *build.gradle* for your core app:

   > ```
   > android {
   >   productFlavors {
   >     // default BuildConfig variables
   >     all {
   >     }
   >     app_1 {
   >         applicationId 'com.yourcompany.app_1' //package name
   >         def variantName='app_1' //name of the variant
   >     }
   >     app_2 {
   >         applicationId 'com.yourcompany.app_2' //package name
   >         def variantName='app_2' //name of the variant
   >     }
   >   }
   > }
   > ```
2. Create *app_1*, *app_2*... *app_x* folders in */src*, each with its own *AndroidManifest.xml*, */src* and */res* folders.
3. Change the current variant in Android Studio:
   [image]

You can find more info on building variant on [Android Tools Project Site](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants).

I can personally vouch for this approach, as I've used this such that a single Android Studio project supports the building of dozens variant, each with its own unique package name, resource files, and custom code that significantly modifies some aspect of the base app, all the while sharing a common base code.