# How to run app in Android Studio with shared library-module from other project?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I use a self-written library-module within another project like it was suggested in

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=105570

and

[Android Studio 0.8.1 Creating Modules without copying files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658422/android-studio-0-8-1-creating-modules-without-copying-files)

I added the lines to settings.gradle and furthermore added the included library via "Project Structure"-Dialog as a dependency to the project. I use Android Studio 1.2.2.

Everything within the IDE looks fine (imports are working, library-code can be browsed and edited, both modules can be "maked" without errors), but I can't seem to launch the project on my phone / emulator.

I get a "classNotFoundException" for the first class from the library that is used in the app.

I copy-pasted the entire project class by class from Eclipse where it would run without problems.

What do I have to do to get the compiled classes of the library into my app onto my phone?

**settings.gradle**

```
include ':app'
include ':Sudoku'
project(':Sudoku').projectDir=new File('/../Libs/sudoku')
```

**build.gradle** (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.frozenmilkmeteoroids.sudokuapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile project(':Sudoku')
}
```

**build.gradle** (library)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Can you post your settings.gradle and the app/build.gradle ?

Comment: edited the post accordingly.

Comment: Id't highly suggest bringing the project in a module or pushing the lib up to a remote online repo like jcenter.

Comment: So Sudoku is the library? Does its build.gradle file apply the com.android.library plugin?

Comment: Is build.gradle (library) inside the Libs/sudoku folder?

Comment: Yes and Yes. These were all generated by AS. @Jared I like to be able to edit the library and the code at the same time...

Comment: @Gabriele Yes, the code within the IDE is all okay, otherwise no import would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also use Android Studio 1.2.2 and here is step by step of how to create the standalone library project and reference it from your main project:

1. create the android project library as you would for a normal android project. Call it **libProjectName**
2. rename the **libProjectName**'s **app** module to **libModuleName**
3. in the **libModuleName's build.gradle** change:
       `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` to `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` and remove **applicationId** from **defaultConfig** section
4. Go to the main project i.e the project to reference **libProjectName**
5. edit `settings.gradle`, add:

> include ':libProjectName:libModuleName'
>
> project(':libProjectName:libModuleName').projectDir=new File('relative/path/libProjectDir/libModuleDir')

6. edit `build.gradle` in **app** Module, add:

> compile project(':libProjectDir:libModuleName')

---

Now assuming that the *module* and *module-directory* name in Sudoku is **moduleSudoku** and applying the steps above, the solution is:

**settings.gradle**

```
include ':app'
include ':Sudoku:moduleSudoku'
project(':Sudoku:moduleSudoku').projectDir=new File('/../Libs/sudoku/moduleSudoku')
```

**build.gradle (app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.frozenmilkmeteoroids.sudokuapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile project(':Sudoku:moduleSudoku')
}
```

**build.gradle (library)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Hello! I am sorry that it took me so long to try it out. Thanks! I would like to furthermore point out that the 'relative/path/libProjectDir/libModuleDir' is '../libProjectName/app' if both projects are lying in the similar folder.