# App erasure, when different apps use the same library

Tags: android, android-studio, module

I have created a project, using library from another my earlier project as in this example

[Android Studio - Creating Modules without copying files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658422/android-studio-creating-modules-without-copying-files)

BUT, after I've compiled a debug version of newer project using phone as debug device, old project has been removed from phone. How I can fix it so, that both apps could co-exist on one phone and at the same time use one library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it by correction `applicationId` parameter in build.gradle