# Reference a library project without copying on Android Studio - Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build-error

I'm trying to migrate my Android projects from Eclipse to **Android Studio**. I have a **library project** which is used in other projects and that's the reason I want it to be separated (not copied in the project). To do this I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24539657/1726308). But I get the following error:

> Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.

I read and tried all the answers on Internet for this error but nothing fixed my problem.

**settings.gradle**

```
include ':my_android_app'
include ':my_android_project_lib'
project(':my_android_project_lib').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../my_android_project_lib')
```

**build.gradle** for my_android_app module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.android.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(path: ':my_android_project_lib')
}
```

**build.gradle** for my_android_app project

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**Edit:** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19832288/1726308) helped me to fix the problem. I had to add the dependencies to the project's build.gradle file.

Comment: Can you try to provide more info/log with the `gradle tasks --info` command as said in this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19583096/1387484 ? Maybe we will find important clues :)

Comment: I am having exact same problem, could you please tell me how did you solve it?

Comment: What dependincies have you added to your project's build.gradle file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you comple with "gradles tasks --info" and see what you've got ?

Otherwise,
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19832288/3351735) you might have something helpfull.

Cheers !